# Custom Docker container Github action is not able to find Node script inside /github/workspace

Tags: node.js, docker, github-actions

I want to create a custom Docker container Github action and started with this action.yml file

```
name: my-action
description: For testing purposes
branding:
  icon: shield
  color: green
inputs:
  my-input:
    description: demo
    required: true
runs:
  using: docker
  image: Dockerfile
```

Next I added some code in a *app.js* file inside the root directory

```
const core = require('@actions/core');

try {
  const myInput = core.getInput('my-input', { required: true });

  core.notice(`Input is: ${myInput}`);
} catch (error) {
  core.setFailed(error.message);
}
```

The Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.13.0-alpine

USER node
WORKDIR /home/node

ADD --chown=node:node . /home/node
RUN npm install

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

To test my action I published my action and created a new workflow

```
name: Run the action

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  run-the-action:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Run the action
        uses: me/my-action@v1.0.0
        with:
          my-input: hello
```

Unfortunately the action crashes with the error message

> Error: Cannot find module '/github/workspace/app.js'

[image]

Maybe I'm missing a mapping from `/home/node` to `/github/workspace`? Does someone know what's wrong or how to fix it?

Please let me know if you need more information!

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible examples, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Based on what you showed, you might be missing the checkout step.

Comment: Please don't share errors as screenshots, but copy the error message. This will help people with similar problems find you question. Also, the error message you showed does not correspond to the YAML you shared.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, that my repo is not mapped to /github/workspace. Did you find a solution?